# net-ssh not able to execute command

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

Why would net-ssh not be able to execute the `useradd` command?

This is my net-ssh code:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, forward_agent: true) do |ssh|
  ssh.open_channel do |ch|
    ch.request_pty
    ch.exec "mkdir /tmp/unicorn"
    ch.exec "sudo groupadd unicorn"
    ch.exec "sudo chgrp unicorn /tmp/unicorn"
    ch.exec "sudo useradd application" do |ch, success|
      if success
        puts 'command worked'
      else
        puts 'command failed'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

All of the commands work except for the `useradd` command. I can log in and run the `useradd` command and a user is added.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your script to add the command

```
puts ch.exec "sudo which useradd"
```

To see if it is a path problem.

I would also add

```
ch.exec 'sudo useradd application 1>/tmp/useradd.log 2>&1'
```

And then go look on the target box to see if there were any errors logged in the `/tmp/useradd.log` file.